# Excel VBA custom functions help dialog

Tags: excel, vba, custom-function

I've been making lots of functions over the years for Excel VBA, but I've always wondered how to make a more detailed help dialog box.

For built in functions, you get something like this:

[image]

How can I do things like this, where it shows the variable type, and if it has a default, what that value is. I've seen some things in the past where if you export the file, then add some code in a text editor, then import it back it, you can get extra functionality that Excel VBA doesn't natively support... wasn't sure if something like that also existed for this type of functionality.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you have a function in your project, doesn't it do this by default?

Comment: I second the above comment. This already happens - not sure what your question is?

Comment: i think he want to add function intellisense (parameter description for function) in VBE, may be...~

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you need. Do you want to add to a **custom made function** such a way of its parameters definition? Or do you want to add extra characteristics for the built functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Instr` is defined in VBA like this:

```
Function InStr([Start], [String1], [String2], [Compare As VbCompareMethod = vbBinaryCompare])
```

`VbCompareMethod` is an enumeration with 3 members. You can define functions to use enumerations as well if you like (even custom ones you create).

In this case, the enumeration is just a choice of a few different integer values. They are useful in limiting which integers are accepted in the routine, for future readability, and in helping the programmer know more easily what options are available using intellisense (I think you are calling intellisense a "help dialog")

Comment: I'll try that and see if it gets me where I was hoping to go. Out of curiosity, how do you look up functions like that? Is it something that has to be done external to Excel VBA or can I do it from within it.

Comment: In the VB editor, press F2 (object explorer) and then search for INSTR

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/enum-statement

Answer (score 0):

Use the following steps to create a custom control.

**Create a User Form:**
To create a custom dialog box, you must create a UserForm. To create a UserForm, click UserForm on the Insert menu in the Visual Basic Editor.

Use the Properties window to change the name, behavior, and appearance of the form. For example, to change the caption on a form, set the Caption property.

**Add Controls to a User Form**
To add controls to a user form, find the control you want to add in the Toolbox, drag the control onto the form, and then drag an adjustment handle on the control until the control's outline is the size and shape you want.

Note Dragging a control, or a number of "grouped" controls from the form back to the Toolbox creates a template of the controls, which can be reused. This is a useful feature for implementing a standard interface for your applications.

After you have added controls to the form, use the commands on the Format menu in the Visual Basic Editor to adjust the control alignment and spacing.

**Initializing Control Properties**
You can initialize controlsat run time by using Visual Basic code in a macro. For example, you could fill a list box, set text values, or set option buttons.

The following example uses the AddItem method to add data to a list box. Then it sets the value of a text box and displays the form.

```
Private Sub GetUserName() 
 With UserForm1 
 .lstRegions.AddItem "North" 
 .lstRegions.AddItem "South" 
 .lstRegions.AddItem "East" 
 .lstRegions.AddItem "West" 
 .txtSalesPersonID.Text = "00000" 
 .Show 
 ' ... 
 End With 
End Sub
```

You can also use code in the Initialize event of a form to set initial values for controls on the form. An advantage to setting initial control values in the Initialize event is that the initialization code stays with the form. You can copy the form to another project, and when you run the Show method to display the dialog box, the controls will be initialized.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize() 
 UserForm1.lstNames.AddItem "Test One" 
 UserForm1.lstNames.AddItem "Test Two" 
 UserForm1.txtUserName.Text = "Default Name" 
End Sub
```

**Control and Dialog Box Events**
After you have added controls to your dialog box or document, you add event procedures to determine how the controls respond to user actions.

User forms and controls have a predefined set of events. For example, a command button has a Click event that occurs when the user clicks the command button, and UserForms have an Initialize event that runs when the form is loaded.

To write a control or form event procedure, open a module by double-clicking the form or control, and select the event from the Procedure list box.

Event procedures include the name of the control. For example, the name of the Click event procedure for a command button named Command1 is Command1_Click.

If you add code to an event procedure and then change the name of the control, your code remains in procedures with the previous name.

For example, assume you add code to the Click event for Command1 and then rename the control to Command2. When you double-click Command2, you will not see any code in the Click event procedure. You will need to move code from Command1_Click to Command2_Click.

To simplify development, it is a good practice to name your controls before writing code.

**To Display a Custom Dialog Box**
To test your dialog box in the Visual Basic Editor, click Run Sub/UserForm on the Run menu in the Visual Basic Editor.

To display a dialog box from Visual Basic, use the Show method. The following example displays the dialog box named UserForm1.

```
Private Sub GetUserName() 
 UserForm1.Show 
End Sub
```

**Using Control Values While Code is Running**
Some controls properties can be set and returned while Visual Basic code is running. The following example sets the Text property of a text box to "Hello."

```
TextBox1.Text = "Hello"
```

The data entered on a form by a user is lost when the form is closed. If you return the values of controls on a form after the form has been unloaded, you get the initial values for the controls rather than the values the user entered.

If you want to save the data entered on a form, you can save the information to module-level variables while the form is still running. The following example displays a form and saves the form data.

```
' Code in module to declare public variables. 
Public strRegion As String 
Public intSalesPersonID As Integer 
Public blnCancelled As Boolean 

' Code in form. 
Private Sub cmdCancel_Click() 
 Module1.blnCancelled = True 
 Unload Me 
End Sub 

Private Sub cmdOK_Click() 
 ' Save data. 
 intSalesPersonID = txtSalesPersonID.Text 
 strRegion = lstRegions.List(lstRegions.ListIndex) 
 Module1.blnCancelled = False 
 Unload Me 
End Sub 

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize() 
 Module1.blnCancelled = True 
End Sub 

' Code in module to display form. 
Sub LaunchSalesPersonForm() 
 frmSalesPeople.Show 
 If blnCancelled = True Then 
 MsgBox "Operation Cancelled!", vbExclamation 
 Else 
 MsgBox "The Salesperson's ID is: " & 
 intSalesPersonID & _ 
 "The Region is: " & strRegion 
 End If 
End Sub
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't believe this has anything to do with the OP's question

Comment: @SmileyFtW In order to create a more detailed function dialog you have to create a customer dialog control. You are very limited to what can be done with the standard control. You can design your own form and use it in the control as the custom dialog box. We have done this with Visual Basic and C# many times and it works very well.

Comment: He wants the intellisense to show the arguments to his function when a user types his function similar to what happens when a user types `Instr`. He doesn't (seem to) be asking how to add a help dialog.

Comment: His question included "I've always wondered how to make a more detailed help dialog box." I guess I misunderstood the question...my bad.